# Simulator zoomed in to half of screen

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, ios8

My simulator is zoomed in to about half of the screen of the iPhone 6 plus. Screenshot below. How does that come and how do I fix that?

**Edit**

If it might help: I'm on the newest 13" mac air running OSX Mavericks.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried pressing CMD + 1, or CMD + 2 or CMD + 3 and see if that still happens? Or, have you tried resetting the simulator?

Comment: Yup.. I have but it still doesn't work

Comment: you can scroll up & down using your scroll wheels.

Answer (score 7):

When on the IOS Simulator go to the tabs on the top and click Window -> Scale ->  % that works best (I used 50%)

Answer (score 1):

1. Select simulator
2. Select Windows ->Scale ->Resize accordingly
3. Done